# How to add custom JavaScripts to Adminhtml config page

Tags: adminhtml, javascript

I am working on a custom Magento extension.
I have created already a page in the admin panel where you can save some settings for the extension.

The url of the page where you can edit the module settings is looking like this:

http://mymagento.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/vivasparser/

Here is my config.xml file:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_Smartparser>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </VivasIndustries_Smartparser>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <smartparser>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Smartparser_Model</class>
            </smartparser>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <smartparser>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Smartparser_Helper</class>
            </smartparser>
        </helpers>
     </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <vivasparser>
                                            <title>vivasparser - All</title>
                                        </vivasparser>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
          <layout>
            <updates>
              <smartparser>
                <file>smartparser.xml</file>
              </smartparser>
            </updates>
          </layout>
    </adminhtml>     
</config>
```

Here is my smartparser.xml file:

```
<layout>
  <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/prototype.js</name></action>
      <action method="addJs"><script>my_extension/jquery.js</script></action>
      <action method="addJs"><script>my_extension/colorpicker.js</script></action>
      <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

Why the javascripts are not loaded ?
I am trying to find `colorpicker.js` in the output HTML source of the page but there is no such thing loaded anywhere.

Can you help me out load these javascripts into my admin panel config page ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `smartparser.xml` the layout handle should be `adminhtml_system_config_edit` instead of `adminhtml_catalog_product_edit`.
Also you forgot a `>` on the line `<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit`.